# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de crear un helper para escribir código JavaScript en rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hola necesito escribir dentro de los tag `<script></script>` en una vista código JavaScript.

Para esto quiero crear un helper, pero no se si esta es la forma correcta.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas crear un helper pues Rails ya tiene uno que hace justamente eso: [javascript_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag)

```
<%= javascript_tag "alert('Sobre rieles')" %>
```

Retorna:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
alert('Sobre rieles')
//]]>
</script>
```